# Pandas: sum multiple columns based on similar consecutive numbers in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following table

```
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
| Nr | Price  | Volume | Transactions |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |  194.6 |    100 |            1 |
|  2 |    195 |     10 |            1 |
|  3 | 194.92 |    100 |            1 |
|  4 | 194.92 |     52 |            1 |
|  5 |  194.9 |     99 |            1 |
|  6 | 194.86 |     74 |            1 |
|  7 | 194.85 |    900 |            1 |
|  8 | 194.85 |     25 |            1 |
|  9 | 194.85 |    224 |            1 |
| 10 |  194.6 |    101 |            1 |
| 11 | 194.85 |     19 |            1 |
| 12 |  194.6 |     10 |            1 |
| 13 |  194.6 |     25 |            1 |
| 14 | 194.53 |     12 |            1 |
| 15 | 194.85 |     14 |            1 |
| 16 |  194.6 |     11 |            1 |
| 17 | 194.85 |     93 |            1 |
| 18 |    195 |     90 |            1 |
| 19 |    195 |    100 |            1 |
| 20 |    195 |     50 |            1 |
| 21 |    195 |     50 |            1 |
| 22 |    195 |     25 |            1 |
| 23 |    195 |      5 |            1 |
| 24 |    195 |    500 |            1 |
| 25 |    195 |    100 |            1 |
| 26 | 195.09 |    100 |            1 |
| 27 |    195 |    120 |            1 |
| 28 |    195 |     60 |            1 |
| 29 |    195 |     40 |            1 |
| 30 |    195 |     10 |            1 |
| 31 |  194.6 |      1 |            1 |
| 32 | 194.99 |      1 |            1 |
| 33 | 194.81 |     20 |            1 |
| 34 | 194.81 |     50 |            1 |
| 35 | 194.97 |     17 |            1 |
| 36 | 194.99 |     25 |            1 |
| 37 |    195 |     75 |            1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
```

For faster testing you can also find here the same table in a pandas dataframe

```
pd_data_before = pd.DataFrame([[1,194.6,100,1],[2,195,10,1],[3,194.92,100,1],[4,194.92,52,1],[5,194.9,99,1],[6,194.86,74,1],[7,194.85,900,1],[8,194.85,25,1],[9,194.85,224,1],[10,194.6,101,1],[11,194.85,19,1],[12,194.6,10,1],[13,194.6,25,1],[14,194.53,12,1],[15,194.85,14,1],[16,194.6,11,1],[17,194.85,93,1],[18,195,90,1],[19,195,100,1],[20,195,50,1],[21,195,50,1],[22,195,25,1],[23,195,5,1],[24,195,500,1],[25,195,100,1],[26,195.09,100,1],[27,195,120,1],[28,195,60,1],[29,195,40,1],[30,195,10,1],[31,194.6,1,1],[32,194.99,1,1],[33,194.81,20,1],[34,194.81,50,1],[35,194.97,17,1],[36,194.99,25,1],[37,195,75,1]],columns=['Nr','Price','Volume','Transactions'])
```

The question is how do we sum up the volume and transactions based on similar consecutive prices? The end result would be something like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
| Nr | Price  | Volume | Transactions |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |  194.6 |    100 |            1 |
|  2 |    195 |     10 |            1 |
|  4 | 194.92 |    152 |            2 |
|  5 |  194.9 |     99 |            1 |
|  6 | 194.86 |     74 |            1 |
|  9 | 194.85 |   1149 |            3 |
| 10 |  194.6 |    101 |            1 |
| 11 | 194.85 |     19 |            1 |
| 13 |  194.6 |     35 |            2 |
| 14 | 194.53 |     12 |            1 |
| 15 | 194.85 |     14 |            1 |
| 16 |  194.6 |     11 |            1 |
| 17 | 194.85 |     93 |            1 |
| 25 |    195 |    920 |            8 |
| 26 | 195.09 |    100 |            1 |
| 30 |    195 |    230 |            4 |
| 31 |  194.6 |      1 |            1 |
| 32 | 194.99 |      1 |            1 |
| 34 | 194.81 |     70 |            2 |
| 35 | 194.97 |     17 |            1 |
| 36 | 194.99 |     25 |            1 |
| 37 |    195 |     75 |            1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------------+
```

You can also find the result ready made in a pandas dataframe below:

```
pd_data_after = pd.DataFrame([[1,194.6,100,1],[2,195,10,1],[4,194.92,152,2],[5,194.9,99,1],[6,194.86,74,1],[9,194.85,1149,3],[10,194.6,101,1],[11,194.85,19,1],[13,194.6,35,2],[14,194.53,12,1],[15,194.85,14,1],[16,194.6,11,1],[17,194.85,93,1],[25,195,920,8],[26,195.09,100,1],[30,195,230,4],[31,194.6,1,1],[32,194.99,1,1],[34,194.81,70,2],[35,194.97,17,1],[36,194.99,25,1],[37,195,75,1]],columns=['Nr','Price','Volume','Transactions'])
```

I managed to achieve this in a for loop. But the problem is that it is very slow when iterating each row. My data set is huge, around 50 million rows. 
Is there any way to achieve this without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common trick to groupby consecutive values is the following:

```
df.col.ne(df.col.shift()).cumsum()
```

We can use that here, then use `agg` to keep the first values of the columns we *aren't* summing, and to sum the values we do want to sum.

```
(df.groupby(df.Price.ne(df.Price.shift()).cumsum())
    .agg({'Nr': 'last', 'Price': 'first', 'Volume':'sum', 'Transactions': 'sum'})
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    Nr   Price  Volume  Transactions 
0    1  194.60     100             1 
1    2  195.00      10             1 
2    4  194.92     152             2 
3    5  194.90      99             1 
4    6  194.86      74             1 
5    9  194.85    1149             3 
6   10  194.60     101             1 
7   11  194.85      19             1 
8   13  194.60      35             2 
9   14  194.53      12             1 
10  15  194.85      14             1 
11  16  194.60      11             1 
12  17  194.85      93             1 
13  25  195.00     920             8 
14  26  195.09     100             1 
15  30  195.00     230             4 
16  31  194.60       1             1 
17  32  194.99       1             1 
18  34  194.81      70             2 
19  35  194.97      17             1 
20  36  194.99      25             1 
21  37  195.00      75             1
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution i was looking for.  I tried playing with the groupby but couldn't get same result.Thank you :)